# How to implement same set of JavaScript/jQuery functions on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to run same method for multiple div elements. The code is give here:

```
<div class="opage" id="oddPage">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="epage" id="evenPage">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="opage" id="oddPage">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="epage" id="evenPage">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="opage" id="oddPage">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="epage" id="evenPage">
    <img>
</div>
```

and JS code is:

```
function flip() {
     document.getElementById("oddPage").style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(-180deg)";
     document.getElementById("evenPage").style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(0deg)";
 }
 function flop() {
     document.getElementById("oddPage").style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(0deg)";
     document.getElementById("evenPage").style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(180deg)";

 }
```

My requirement is if I click on odd page flip() is called and if I click on even page odd function is called.

I did it using

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.opage').click(flip);
    $('.epage').click(flop);
});
```

It works fine on first odd and first even page page but not on next pages. Then I came to know that multiple divs cannot have same Ids. So changed ids to oddPage1, evenPage1, oddPage2, evenPage2, oddPage3, evenPage3 and then tried it with getElementbyClassName in flip() and flip() but it did not work at all.

Then i tried this also

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.opage').click(function(){
        $('opage').css('-webkit-Transform', 'rotateY(-180deg)');
        $('epage').css('-webkit-Transform', 'rotateY(0deg)';
    });

    $('.epage').click(function(){
        $('opage').css('-webkit-Transform', 'rotateY(0deg)';
        $('epage').css('-webkit-Transform', 'rotateY(-180deg)');
    });
});
```

But it is not working. I am new to jquery and learning it gradually.

Comment: You probably want to use classes not ID's (since you can only have one of each ID on a page) - but somthing like `document.getElementById("oddPage").addEventListener("click", function() { flip(); },false);` `document.getElementById("evenPage").addEventListener("click", function() { flop(); },false);` for what you have?

Comment: Please do some basic research on [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and its documentation. It is VERY well documented and you'll find your answer quicker, as well as other useful tools and info

Comment: Thank you for your response.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#oddPage').click(flip);
$('#evenPage').click(flop);
```

if there are multiple elements with this id, change it to a class because ids are unique and reference it with a `.`

```
$('.oddPage').click(flip);
$('.evenPage').click(flop);
```

Comment: If this is the solution, it should be flip and flop without ()

Comment: Thank you for your response:)

Comment: @MB it is working but only when i put it into the script tag.. but if i put it into different .js file then pass its link to the head tag then it is not working.. can you please tell me why??

Comment: because its jquery, you need to wrap the code in a `$(document).ready(function(){})` so that it runs after the html is rendered see https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @M B can you please recheck the code and edits I made in this question and tell me where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: your missing the `.` in the selector to set the css

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the following w/Jquery:

```
function flip() {
 //Something on odd page;
 //Something on even page;
}
function flop() {
 //Something on odd page;
 // Something on even page;
}

$('#evenPage').click(function(){
    flop();
});
$('#oddPage').click(function(){
    flip();
});
```

If you have multiple uses of `evenPage` and `oddPage` you will need to change these to classes.